# Работа с базой данных и DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, winforms, datagridview

Есть 2 справочника, контрагенты и банковские реквизиты. В справочнике контрагенты находятся поля: контактное лицо, должность, фирма, адрес и телефон; а в справочнике банковские реквизиты поля: расчетный счет, наименование банка, БИК и адрес. Эти справочники должны находиться на 2 разных формах, а их данные помещены в `DataGridView`, где пользователь может вносить новые данные и изменять их. Также существует 3-ая форма, которая представляет акт данные которого содержатся в `DataGridView` и в которой название полей совпадает со справочниками, а также присутствует поле номер и дата договора, а значение поля, например, "контактное лицо" пользователь может выбрать из выпадающего списка, который ссылается на поле из таблицы справочника.

Помогите все это реализовать

Данный код для формы **Контрагенты**, но есть вопрос, данные с файла считываются, но заносятся в виде непонятных символов, данные написаны на русском языке, как можно исправить?

Вот запись в файле:

```
Контактное лицо, Должность,Фирма,Адрес,Телефон
Иванов И.И.,юрист,ОАО "Лесхоз",г.Москва пер.Солнечный 25, 345678
```

```cs
public partial class Contractor : Form
{
    public Contractor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Contractor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection StrCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Serega\Desktop\SVCHVS\SVCHVS;Extended Properties=text");
        //Строка для выборки данных
        string Select1 = "SELECT * FROM [Contractor.txt]";
        //Создание объекта Command
        OleDbCommand comand1 = new OleDbCommand(Select1, StrCon);
        //Определяем объект Adapter для взаимодействия с источником данных
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(comand1);
        //Определяем объект DataSet
        DataSet AllTables = new DataSet();
        //Открываем подключение
        StrCon.Open();
        //Заполняем DataSet таблицей из источника данных
        adapter1.Fill(AllTables);
        //Заполняем обект datagridview для отображения данных на форме
        dataGridView1.DataSource = AllTables.Tables[0];
        StrCon.Close();
    }
    private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index); //удаление
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберите строку для удаления.", "Ошибка.");
        }
    }
    private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = product.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = department.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = sold.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = stock.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = coast.Text;
        }
        else
        {
        }

    }
    private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Удаление", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Serega\Desktop\SVCHVS\SVCHVS", false, Encoding.Default);
            //Добавление имен столбцов
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                sw.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText);
                if (j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
                    sw.Write(",");
            }
            sw.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    sw.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                    if (j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
                        sw.Write(",");
                }
                sw.WriteLine();
            }
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = product.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = department.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = sold.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = stock.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = coast.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберите строку для редактирования.", "Ошибка.");
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            product.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            department.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            sold.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            stock.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            coast.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

[image: Пример формы]

Comment: В строке соединения укажите используемую кодировку: `CharacterSet=...`

Comment: Никогда не используйте кодировку `Encoding.Default` - она разная на разных компьютерах. Всегда задавайте какую-либо конкретную кодировку, например, `Encoding.Unicode` или `Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: `StreamWriter` не использует провайдер, он принимает только _путь_ к файлу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov кодировка для файлов - UTF-8. Здесь нет альтернатив.

Comment: @aepot - Для работы с внешним миром, с сетью, да, utf-8 - стандарт. Однако, если приложение пишет и читает свои собственные текстовые данные, то utf-16 позволит избежать лишних конвертаций, ведь строки в дотнете в этой кодировке.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov UTF-16LE или BE? Там тоже своей путаницы хватит. Я работаю с 16 языками (включая японский, тайский и все китайские), у меня везде UTF-8, и в буфере обмена, и в файлах, и сети. В какое именно место мне надо подмешать UTF-16, чтобы стало лучше?

Comment: @aepot - System.String и System.Char - utf-16. Не знаю, что тут ещё добавить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я не могу использовать эту кодировку во внешних источниках данных, примерно нигде. UTF-16 живет внутри .NET и за пределы рантайма ему дороги нет, ибо UTF-8 - стандарт. Во всяком случае, в наше время. Что уж говорить, если консоль до сих пор CP866.

Comment: @aepot - Я и говорю, что для связи с внешним миром - utf-8. А если приложение пишет и читает текстовые файлы для своих собственных нужд, то utf-16 будет работать быстрее, т. к. не будет лишних перекодировок.